# Cleaner way to catch an error in a chain of nested promises?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm new to working with promises and am noticing that, in order to catch an error in a chain of nested promises, I need to invoke the catch method on each promise in the chain. Is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
      poll.pollForCandidates().then((candidates) => {
        let clientId = candidates[0].clientId;
        poll.getUnprocessedCandidates({context, clientId, candidates})
          .then((unprocessedCandidates) => {
            console.log(unprocessedCandidates);
            poll.addCandidatesToQueue(context, unprocessedCandidates)
              .then((processedCandidates) => {
                console.log(processedCandidates);
                poll.addCandidatesToTable(processedCandidates)
                  .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error); 
              })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error); 
          })
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.done(error); 
      });
    };
```

Comment: Oh no! I remember it is a very common anti pattern. Return promises from `.then`. And the next `.then` handler will have the returned promise's resolved/reject value

Comment: I think that "async" library would be a better approach. Did you try async waterfall?

Comment: Use `await`. But with your existing code, you can also remove all the `.catch(error => console.done(error)` calls except the last one. They do nothing.

Comment: Nearly all those `.catch()` statements are wrong for several reasons.  You should chain your statements and only put a `.catch()` in the places you actually need to handle the error.  Plus, these `.catch()` statements that only log and don't return anything actually change the promises from rejected to fulfilled which is likely NOT what you want.

Answer (score 4):

This is the shorter way to do it:

```
poll.pollForCandidates()
    .then((candidates) => poll.getUnprocessedCandidates({ context, candidates[0].clientId, candidates }))
    .then((unprocessedCandidates) => poll.addCandidatesToQueue(context, unprocessedCandidates))
    .then((processedCandidates) => poll.addCandidatesToTable(processedCandidates))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Explanation:

This is called *composing promises*, and it's one of the great superpowers of promises. Each function will only be called when the previous promise has resolved, and it'll be called with that promise's output.

There are three things you can do inside the then function:

1. return another promise
2. return a synchronous value (or undefined)
3. throw a synchronous error

Here in the example above, we return a promise, so we can use `.then` to continue the *composing promises*.

At the end, the `console.log` gets the result and call the `console.log` with it. (Same with the `console.error`)

That's it. Once you understand this trick, you understand promises.

You can continue reading about it here:
[We have a problem with promises - By: Nolan Lawson](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

Answer (score 2):

Like @bugwheels94 mentioned, you can return your promises from within `.then` and add another `.then` outside of the previous `.then`. Also, `.then` can take 2 arguments - the second one is for catching errors. It's a bit difficult to explain in words so here's an example.

```
poll.pollForCandidates()
  .then((candidates) => {
    let clientId = candidates[0].clientId;

    return poll.getUnprocessedCandidates({context, clientId, candidates})
      .then((unprocessedCandidates) => {
        console.log(unprocessedCandidates);
        return poll.addCandidatesToQueue(context, unprocessedCandidates)
      }, (error) => {
         console.log(error); 
      })
      .then((processedCandidates) => {
        console.log(processedCandidates);
        return poll.addCandidatesToTable(processedCandidates)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error); 
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }), (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Edit**: @jfriend00 brought up a good about using all of those `.catch` methods. Here's what the code would look like with a single `.catch` at the end of the chain.

```
poll.pollForCandidates()
  .then((candidates) => {
    let clientId = candidates[0].clientId;

    return poll.getUnprocessedCandidates({context, clientId, candidates})
      .then((unprocessedCandidates) => {
        console.log(unprocessedCandidates);
        return poll.addCandidatesToQueue(context, unprocessedCandidates)
      })
      .then((processedCandidates) => {
        console.log(processedCandidates);
        return poll.addCandidatesToTable(processedCandidates)
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Edit 2**: Removing those extra `console.log` statements allows you to make it even cleaner.

```
poll.pollForCandidates()
  .then((candidates) => {
    let clientId = candidates[0].clientId;

    return poll.getUnprocessedCandidates({context, clientId, candidates})
      .then(unprocessedCandidates => poll.addCandidatesToQueue(context, unprocessedCandidates))
      .then(poll.addCandidatesToTable)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: All those `.catch()` statements cause problems.  See my comment on the OP's question for details.  One should generally be able to code with far fewer `.catch()` statements since error propagate automatically in promise chains.

Comment: Good point. I was just attempting to give the same functionality as the original code. I'll make an edit.

Comment: So, that `catch` tied to the outermost `then` will catch the error that might be produced by any of the chained `then`s?

Comment: @MichaelP. - As long as you return nested promises from within `.then()` handlers allowing them to chain to the previous chain, a rejection anywhere in the chain will propagate all the way back to the top level and to the one `.catch()` at the end.  This is where promises really shine (error handling in complex multi-step async processes).